# How to use Mathematica in academic paper writing?

Tags: notebooks

The Mathematica notebook is a great avenue for inspiring and realising research ideas. However, I do feel there are several missing jigsaws in the picture of writing academic paper fully in Mathematica:

1. citation management: there is one but in fact broken on Mac; it would be great to integrate the [CSL approach](https://citationstyles.org).
2. references and captions for figures/tables: (at least I haven't figured out how to manage this). One ideal example can be found in the `pandoc` world using [`pandoc-crossref`](https://github.com/lierdakil/pandoc-crossref), which I find is very sleek.

So I'm wondering how can we build a sleek workflow in pure Mathematica for academic paper writing?

One recent promising effort might be [`M2MD`](https://github.com/kubaPod/M2MD) that can convert a notebook into a markdown file, which may shed some light in implementation of the wanted features above.

Comment: You explained what you would like to achieve, but maybe it is good to say why you want to go this way?

Comment: @yarchik I would prefer a one-stop solution for my research production. Jupyter notebook in a sense can be a good alternative but I do prefer Mathematica as my top one research workshop.

Comment: Unusual question? It is hard managing Notebooks, LaTeX documents, (citations) reference management, and how to best distribute? (PDF, e-PUB?, Notebook??) It would be nice if there was an easy answer. Wolfram Language and CDFs are all about "sharing maths" in a browser. Maybe start there? Wish had better news, but it seems to be destined to always be a struggle?

Comment: But some journals prefer docx format, others prefer LaTeX and even provide style files. Is it cost management? I am not using it, but it seems MSWord is pretty cheap nowadays..

Comment: I was wondering at least a pathway to other easier channels can be built within Mathematica, e.g., the M2MD package I mentioned in the question for exporting notebooks to markdown: given the popularity of markdown and its technical variants, it might be possible for academic writing in Mathematica?

Comment: I use a Wiki to keep URLs straight and easy to self-comment and document. Browser data should be maintained and viewed in a browser. Jupyter seems very interesting & Kubernetes. Chio

Comment: @yarchik, yes, it's absolutely true `docx` is preferred by quite a few journals. If we can export `nb` to `docx`, it would be appreciated. And `pandoc` can be the nexus for a bunch of such conversion: it's just the gateway from Mathematica to pandoc is largely missing.

Comment: I'd argue against this. A mathematica notebook is not among the accepted formats for any of the journals I publish in (chemistry) and, I suspect, for math and physics $\LaTeX$ reigns supreme, with MS Word files coming second. Practically speaking, you would have to reconstruct the authoring toolchain from scratch, only to get to a practically unusable final product in its native format that would still have to be exported / converted. Publishing houses want *editable* submissions, so converting to e.g. PDF would not be enough.

Comment: Also, mutability for a manuscript authoring tool might be attractive in the short run, but is probably not a very good idea: a few years down the line some package breaks / some incompatible changes are made, and you no longer can access / edit / work with your original manuscript. Also, by definition *everybody* in your field has access to the "normal" most common authoring tools, so collaboration is easy if you use those, but horribly painful otherwise. And Mathematica is emphatically *not* a common manuscript authoring tool.

Comment: I wouldn't look at Wolfram tech as a tool for conventional paper writing. But it is definitely capable at publishing research in a more modern media format. Take a look at https://distill.pub/ for example.

Comment: But magazines only need docx or pdf...